# Property in class is IEnumerable<TDto> get TDto.A == a

Tags: c#, linq

So I have a class is something like this

```
public class Order
{
    //some other stuff ... 
    //setting the internal _orderItems collection ...
    IEnumerable<OrderItems> OrderItems { get { return _orderItems; }
}

public class OrderItem
{
    //other stuff
    public string ProductName {get; set;}
}
```

If I have a collection of orders of some sort and have access via linq to the order, something like

```
 myOrderRespository.Where(x=>x.OrderItems)
```

Then I only have access to getEnumerator there, waht I would like it to be able to do something like

```
 myOrderRespository.Where(x=>x.OrderItems.ProductName == "Blah")
```

Is this possible?
this is a made up scenario and its pseudo code I m trying to simplify the problem so its easy to explain ( so please forgive me if there are a few errors)
Cheers

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You probably are looking for something like:

```
var results = myOrderRepository.Where(x => x.OrderItems.Any(item => item.ProductName == "Blah"));
```

This will return all `Order` instances with at least one OrderItem that has the ProductName of "Blah".